# Django on Ubuntu VPS [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.json'

Tags: python, json, linux, django, ubuntu

I have my django project running on an ubuntu VPS set up for development. I have several JSON files in the root of the project (committed to version control) that I need to access.

The following works without issue on my local machine (OSX 10.9.5):

```
details_raw = open('file1.json', 'r')
```

But returns `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.json'` on my dev server. I'm almost certain I have accomplished this very task on other remote servers set up the same way.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do you need os.join or to usethe full path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current dir on the server is not the same as project root.  You need to `chdir` to project root or use full path to JSON file.

If you use Django 1.7 with standard `settings.py` then try something like this:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

file_name = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'file1.json')
details_raw = open(file_name, 'r')
```